# Add new content to object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-context

I'm facing some issue trying to stock data inside an array.
I've created a component input which I use many times. Each input stock different data about a user. I would like to format an object where all this information will be stock in a json type. For this I use react `context`. But the thing is that, each time I write data inside my field, the previous one is erased. I know how to get insert inside an array after the previous state, but in the case of an object, `...prevState` is not working.
Moreover, how can I use the label I pass as props inside the json ? Because I put `label` in thinking that it would actually take the props value, but it doesn't and it just fill the data with `label`.

This is the component

```js
type Label = {
    label: string
    type: string
}

export const Forms = ({ label, type }: Label) => {    
    const {userData, setUserData} = useContext(RegisterContext)

    const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault()
     // setUserData(prev => [prev, e.target.value])  this is what I used to do with array
        setUserData({type: e.target.value})
    }

    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col w-64">
            <span className="text-appiness-darkblue">{label}</span>
            <input onChange={handleChange} type={type} className="rounded-md bg-appiness-green focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-appiness-darkblue"/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

and this is how I call it

```js
<div className="grid grid-cols-2 justify-items-center w-5/12">
    <Forms type="text" label="Username"/>
    <Forms type="string" label="First name"/>
    <Forms type="string" label="Last name"/>
    <Forms type="string" label="Email"/>
    <Forms type="password" label="Password"/>
    <Forms type="date" label="Date of Birth"/>
</div>
```

Comment: `setUserData(prev => { ...prev, type: e.target.value })`?

Comment: @raina77ow I've already tried that, and I received a `a spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter` on the `...prev`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out to spread the state and the `type` field:

```
 const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setUserData({...userData, type: e.target.value})
    }
```

Comment: is there anyway  I could dynamically use my `label` passed on props as a key ? Because I tried
`label: e.target.value` and it wrote label instead of the password, username etc

Comment: please explain more

Comment: as you can see when I call the component, I pass it props, one of them being the label name, example "email", "password" etc, when I fill the userData hooks, I would like to dynamically use this label as a "key" for the json. In the code you wrote, I would like the `type` because the value of the label props

Comment: you could try something like `setUserData({...userData, [label]: e.target.value})`